# web3 event keeps on running after resolve()

Tags: web3js

In my project I have a contractInteract function that interacts with a blockchain contract returning a promise. I add a "confirmation" event. This event logs "Confirmed!" every confirmation and once it reaches 5 confirmations it resolves. This is the function:

```
function contractInteract() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var confirmationCounter = 0
        const contractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(contract.ABI, contract.address)

        contractInstance.methods.contractFunction(0).send({
            from: address,
            gasPrice: "35000000000"
        }).on('confirmation', () => {
            confirmationCounter++
            console.log("Confirmed!")

            if(confirmationCounter == 5) {
                console.log("Transaction confirmed 5 times.")
                resolve()
            }
        }).on('error', function(error) {
            reject(error)
        })
    })
}
```

I then call the aforementioned function with:

```
const init = async () => {
    await contractInteract()
    console.log("Finished")
}
```

The function executes correctly. Once it reaches 5 confirmations it first logs `Transaction confirmed 5 times.` And then logs `Finished`. Only issue is that the `.on('confirmation')` event keeps on running, meaning that it keeps on printing `Confirmed!`. I also tried returning the resolve() but it still continued running. How can I exit from the event? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the issue by assigning a variable to `const swap = contractInstance.methods.contractFunction(0).send(...`

And then in the if statement I run `swap.removeAllListeners()`.